# jquery datepicker UTC

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

So when I save an event, I save it as UTC.  Offset is correct for events, and they're shown correctly.  I have the datepicker... if I click a day, it returns the local timezone date.  So, if I'm at -7, events that are 02:30am 03/28/13 should show up when I click 03/27/13.  They're not.

Can I make the date I click be the UTC date?

Comment: I've confused myself.  It is checking the database for the exact date I'm feeding it... so datepicker is using the UTC time.  I want the date I pick to be the local date.  Am I making any sense?